# How should the log4j.properties put inside the war file using ANT build tool?

Tags: ant, log4j, war

I have a log4j.properties that sit right under the src folder. When I building my war file using ANT tool, the particular properties file wasn't pack inside WEB-INF/classes folder, and it was right under the "root" directory of the war file (if you unwar it). I heard from my colleague mention that this is not correct. May I know is this true? If no, how should I correct it?

THanks @!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `log4j.properties` (or any other resource loaded from the classpath) should be at the root of your Java source folder (`src/main/java`, `build/main`, `src`, `JavaSource`, or however you have your project configured).

In the WAR, it should be under `WEB-INF/classes`, not at the root (as if you unzipped it).

If this is not the case, being able to see your ANT build file would be very helpful.  You should have something like this line configured within your `war` task:

```
<classes dir="build/main"/>
```

As long as you have a `build/main/log4j.properties` in your Ant basedir, this should work as you're expecting.

Comment: May I know how to put log4j.properties inside WEB-INF/classes using ANT?

Comment: war ant task doesn't support copy task.

Comment: @huahsin68 - Please see my updated answer.  (And no, you shouldn't need the copy task.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After ant task done the compilation on the source code, I use the copy ant task to manually copy the propeties file into class folder. When come war to task, everything inside classes folder will be pack into WEB-INF/classes directory.